# Save remote image to camera roll in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm getting nothing but errors from the ReactNative CameraRoll's `saveImageWithTag` function. Saving a local image with something like:

```
CameraRoll.saveImageWithTag('./path/to/myimage.png');
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

gives me the error:

```
Error: The file “myimage.png” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.(…)
```

`./path/to/myimage.png` in this case is the path I'd use to `require` an image for an `Image` source. What should the full path be for a local image be? Do I need to store them differently to make them accessible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## 0. Short answer

Use [RNFS](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) to locate the local image.

## 1. For your title 'Save remote image to camera roll in React Native'

The keyword is `remote`.

Before using [CameraRoll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html), we should [link the library](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html) first.

[image]

Then, I create one `Image` and one `Button`:

```
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image ref="logoImage"
            style={{ height:50, width: 50 }}
            source={{uri: 'http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
          />
          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this._handlePressImage} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Save Image</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  },
```

When I press the button, the program will save the image to camera roll:

```
  _handlePressImage: function() {
    console.log('_handlePressImage.');

    var uri = this.refs.logoImage.props.source;
    console.log(uri);
    CameraRoll.saveImageWithTag(uri, function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  },
```

`React Native` warns me that the API is deprecated, just use `promise` instead:

```
var promise = CameraRoll.saveImageWithTag(uri);
promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log('save succeeded ' + result);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('save failed ' + error);
});
```

Now, we can see the logo image in our camera roll.

## 2. For your real problem in your content

Despite your title says `remote`, your code uses the `local` path.

Give the path `'./path/to/myimage.png'`, I assume that the image path is relative to the `.js` file. That is, your image is not relative to the final running app, so it can not find the image file.

Now change the `Image` to use local file:

```
<Image ref="logoImage"
  style={{ height:50, width: 50 }}
  source={require('./logo_og.png')}
/>
```

and save the image like this:

```
var promise = CameraRoll.saveImageWithTag('./logo_og.png');
```

which results in:

[image]

Because `CameraRoll API` is corresponding to the `Native Component`, which belongs to the final running app, not the javascript.

## 3. Use [RNFS](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) to save local images

First run the command below:

```
npm install react-native-fs --save
```

and then link the library.

After Putting the image under `Library/Caches`:

[image]

we can save the local image:

```
var cacheImagePath = RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath+"/logo_og.png";
console.log(cacheImagePath);
var promise = CameraRoll.saveImageWithTag(cacheImagePath);
promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log('save succeeded ' + result);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('save failed ' + error);
});
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks! Yeah, I figured out that I could just use the remote url but forgot to change the question title. Still struggling with local files, though. I'll take a look at react-native-fs. Any reason you're using the CachesDirectory instead of the DocumentDirectory?

Comment: @nicholas Either CachesDirectory or DocumentDirectory is just an example :)

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: Saving animated gifs only saves the first frame on iOS. The photos app will generally not show animation in any case, but even after emailing or otherwise sharing the gif and opening it up, it seems to only be a static gif... Any ideas as to what's going on there?

Comment: @JasonLee How can I save image from remote url such as ‘http://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png’ in Android??

Answer (score 2):

Use this **saveToCameraRoll** method.

```
import { CameraRoll } from 'react-native';

 CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(url)
    .then(alert('Done', 'Photo added to camera roll!')) 
    .catch(err => console.log('err:', err))
}
```

The user's permission is required in order to access the Camera Roll on devices running iOS 10 or later. Add the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key in your Info.plist with a string that describes how your app will use this data. This key will appear as Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description in Xcode. If you are targeting devices running iOS 11 or later, you will also need to add the NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key in your Info.plist.

Comment: is deprecated now :
you can use : https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll