# React Native ref/ reference on the Component is not working

Tags: react-native, react-ref

I am developing a React Native application. What I am doing now in my application is that I am trying to use reference/ ref on my component.

This is my code

```
class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  _handleDownloadButton = () => {
    var uri = this.refs.logoImage.props.source;
    var promise = CameraRoll.saveImageWithTag(uri);
    promise.then(function(result) {
      console.log('save succeeded ' + result);
      Alert.alert('Saved')
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('save failed ' + error);
      Alert.alert('Error')
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
        onPress={() => {
          this._handleDownloadButton();
        }}
        title="Download photo">
        </Button>
        <Image ref="logoImage" style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: 'https://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/05/22/11/davidbeckham.jpg?w968' }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Gallery;
```

When I click on the download button, I got the following error.

```
Cannot find property source of undefined
```

[image]

I tried this too.

```
<Image ref={ref => this.image = ref} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: 'https://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/05/22/11/davidbeckham.jpg?w968' }} />
```

with

```
var uri = this.image.props.source;
```

I got the same error. I tried this too.

In the constructor I added

```
this.image = React.createRef();
```

component

```
<Image ref={this.image} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: 'https://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/05/22/11/davidbeckham.jpg?w968' }} />
```

with

```
var uri = this.image.props.source;
```

Comment: Just a simple question. Why would you try to access the source you’re passing to Image component like that? You can keep that in state and access it or if that is not varying, access it as a constant. I’m kinda curious to know why you are trying to access it like that?

Comment: I get the uri of the image component, then save it into the camera roll. Following this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134499/save-remote-image-to-camera-roll-in-react-native.

Answer (score 0):

You are using string refs which are considered as [legacy and have some issue](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).

Here is the modified code of how you use the [new approach](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) with `createRef`.

```
class Gallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.image = createRef();
  }

  _handleDownloadButton = () => {
    const imageRef = this.image.current;
    if (imageRef) {
      const url = imageRef.props.source;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image ref={this.image} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: 'https://static.standard.co.uk/s3fs-public/thumbnails/image/2016/05/22/11/davidbeckham.jpg?w968' }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it. But not working. Please, see my updated question.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
 onPress={() => {
          this._handleDownloadButton();
        }}
```

to

```
onPress={this._handleDownloadButton}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried it. Not working. Please, see my updated question.

Comment: Hi. Just the same.

Comment: Then try  var that=this;  var uri = that.refs.logoImage.props.source; in function _handleDownloadButton

Comment: Hi, it is not the issue. I know what you are trying to do. Since I am using the arrow function, it is fine.